# Why does List declaration is not working in c#

Tags: c#, list, variable-declaration

I am trying to declare the List like below code.

`public List<string> t1,t2,t3 = new List<string>();`

When I am trying to add something to List then it gives me error of was null on run time but do not give me compile time error.

```
public List<string> t1 = new List<string>();
public List<string> t2 = new List<string>();
public List<string> t3 = new List<string>();
```

While declaration of individual is working perfectly.

Please someone explain this and thank you in advance.

Comment: There is nothing to explain, this is basic C# syntax. with `t1,t2,t3 = new...` you only assign the new reference to `t3`, not to `t1` and not to `t2`. To achieve that you'd need `public List<string> t1 = new List<string(), t2 = new List<string>(), t3 = new List<string>();`

Comment: In the first example, you only initialize `t3`?

Comment: In the same way `int a,b,c = 3;` only initializes `c` to `3`, but `a` and `b` are still `0` (the default value). Or actually they are uninitialized.

Comment: @RenéVogt: I would post it as an answer because there is nothing more to say about this than what you already have.

Comment: @Flater: Well actually... even if it worked the way OP expected, it still would break his program, because there would be only one List object and three references to it.

Comment: Also, please note that public fields are considered bad practice. You better make them public properties instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm not how that exactly pertains to my comment. But in either case, even if this feature existed, this can be a compiler optimization where it knows to actually instantiate individual objects. I'm not saying that's a given, but it could be equally possible.

Comment: Perhaps OP - also - expects lists to be immutable? That would explain why having three references to the same list is not a worry, nor having them public. Shyam, List<T> is not immutable. You could look for  System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList<T> if that is what you want.

Comment: Just to add a touch more (from a different perspective).  You are declaring three variables of type `List<string>` (`t1`, `t2` and `t3`).  You are also creating one object of type  `List<string>` with your `new List<string()` expression.  A reader of your code now has to think _"OK, what does that do?"_  Does it initialize `t1` to point to the new list, does it initialize `t3` to point to the new list, or does it initialize all three to point to the same new list?  You should always write code to make the reader's job easier.  Don't assume he/she knows the edge conditions of the language.

Comment: @Flater: Just that there is in fact more explanation possible.  I think Flydog's comment has it pretty comprehensively covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare multiple variables in one line as following IF they are of the same type:

```
        // Declare and initialize three local variables with same type.
        // ... The type int is used for all three variables.
        //
        int i = 5, y = 10, x = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", i, y, x);
```